# How to get count of records based on two columns from the same table when either columns could be null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: **PLAN** and **PRODUCT**

**PLAN** table has **DOCUMENT_ID** and **PRODUCT_ID** column. Both these are nullable columns. ie, A Plan can contain either Document or Product or both.

I have to get count of Plans based on given Product IDs. I also need to consider the Documents for Products from the **PRODUCT** table while getting this count for **PLAN**. How should I write such a query? Thanks.

Here is a sample view of the tables:

```
DOCUMENT table
+------------+-
|Document_Id |
+------------+
|          1 |         
|          2 |           
|          3 |                    
+------------+

PRODUCT table
+------------+-------------+
| Product_Id | Document_Id |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 |           1 |
|          2 |           2 |
|          3 |           1 |
|          4 |           2 |
|          5 |           3 |
+------------+-------------+

PLAN table
+---------+------------+-------------+
| Plan_Id | Product_Id | Document_Id |
+---------+------------+-------------+
|       1 | 1          | 2           |
|       2 | NULL       | 3           |
|       3 | 3          | NULL        |
|       4 | NULL       | 1           |
|       5 | 5          | 2           |
+---------+------------+-------------+
```

Note: In PLAN table either Product_Id or Document_Id can be NULL not both.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: I might be tempted to redesign the plan table with an id and a type column specifying to which thing id refers

Comment: How are the ProductIDs 'given' are you passing in a comma delimited list? Or are they pulling from another query?

Comment: Yes Product IDs are passed in the WHERE clause as comma delimited list. I am trying to create the desired results table to display on UI and update the question as suggested by @GordonLinoff

Comment: Please add the foreign key relationships.